# How to retrieve infromation from inside the tag of an xml in java android?

Tags: android, xml, tags, extract

I have seen a lot of answers online but they are always about data of the type

```
<tag>Data is here</tag>
```

What I am asking is when the data is inside the tag itself. such as in this case:

```
<quote f25="3M Company" f6="162.11" f14="-0.59" f15="-0.3626" f2="162.443" f3="161.21">26 Mar 15:05</quote>
<quote f25="Alcoa Inc." f6="12.89" f14="-0.08" f15="-0.6168" f2="13.01" f3="12.86">26 Mar 15:05</quote>
```

How can I retrieve the name value and movement. so f25, f6 and f14??

Answer (score 0):

You can use element.getAttribute("f25"); to extract attribute values